# Why does selecting and renaming columns of data.table using the list alias .() return an error?

Tags: r, data.table

Below is my data table:

`DT = data.table(ID = c("a","b","c"), a=1:3, b=10:12, c=100:102)`

```
   ID a  b   c
1:  a 1 10 100
2:  b 2 11 101
3:  c 3 12 102
```

I am trying to select columns a and b and renaming the selected columns to column1 and column2, respectively

`DT[, .(a=column1, b=column2)]`

But get the below error, not sure why. 
Error in eval(jsub, SDenv, parent.frame()) : object 'column1' not found

Per the documentation page for the package, I would have expected the above to work
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html

Comment: it would be other way `DT[, .(column1 = a, column2 = b)]`, but it will only get the columns that was in side the `.()`'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `setnames` which will name by reference

```
setnames(DT, c('a', 'b'), paste0('column', 1:2))
DT
#   ID column1 column2   c
#1:  a       1      10 100
#2:  b       2      11 101
#3:  c       3      12 102
```

---

If we are `select`ing the column and renaming, it would be the other way i.e. instead of `a = column1`, it is `column1 = a`

```
DT[, .(column1 = a, column2 = b)]
```

Comment: Agreed, but curious if wrapping the column renames in .() is not supported anymore.

Comment: Also, to clarify I am not trying to name by reference, just renaming columns in the selection

Comment: @nthobservation. Are you tryiing to update the original dataset or just selecting the required columns.  If that is the case `DT[, .(column1 = a, column2 = b)]`

Comment: The latter and that worked. So had the order wrong.